# java StructuredTaskScope.joinUntil is not working for blocking Callable

Tags: java, concurrency

In Java, 
Can i input a callable (that runs forever) to a StructuredTaskScope,
and use joinUntil function to set a timeout,
and expect it to be stop automatically?

Please see the implementation [here](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.tst.thread/blob/main/src/main/java/com/tugalsan/tst/thread/Main.java)

Here is the callable that runs forever

```
Callable<String> callableBlocking = () -> {
d.ci("fetchFail.callableBlocking", "begin");
   while (true) {
      d.ci("fetchFail.callableBlocking", "while");
      TS_ThreadWait.of(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
   }
// d.ci("fetchFail.callableBlocking", "never ends");
// return "4";
};
```

----------- UPDATE ---------------------
Please find the simplified code to recreate the situation

```
Consumer<String> log = msg -> System.out.println("log -> " + msg);
Consumer<Duration> wait = duration -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(duration);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
};
Callable<String> callableBlocking = () -> {
    log.accept("fetchFail.callableBlocking.begin");
    while (true) {
        log.accept("fetchFail.callableBlocking.while");
        wait.accept(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
    }
//  log.accept("fetchFail.callableBlocking.neverEnds");
//  return "never returns";
};
var scope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure();
try {
    var future = scope.fork(callableBlocking);
    scope.joinUntil(Instant.now().plusSeconds(1));
    scope.throwIfFailed();
    log.accept("result: " + future.resultNow());
} catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException | ExecutionException e) {
    log.accept(e.getClass().getName() + ":" + e.getMessage());
    if (e instanceof TimeoutException) {
        scope.shutdown();
        log.accept("INFO: shutdown triggered");
    }
} finally {
    scope.close();
}
```

CONSOLE:

```
tugal@TULAP /cygdrive/c/me/codes/com.tugalsan/tst/com.tugalsan.tst.thread 
$ java --enable-preview --add-modules jdk.incubator.concurrent -jar target/com.tugalsan.tst.thread-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.concurrent 
log -> fetchFail.callableBlocking.begin 
log -> fetchFail.callableBlocking.while 
log -> fetchFail.callableBlocking.while 
log -> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:null 
log -> INFO: shutdown triggered
log -> fetchFail.callableBlocking.while 
log -> fetchFail.callableBlocking.while 
log -> fetchFail.callableBlocking.while 
log -> fetchFail.callableBlocking.while 
...
```

Comment: bizarre question. please follow the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ursa you r right. I will simplify whole code to few lines, and update my question on Monday. I think continuation class is capable of pausing a thread, not killing. If it were, they would have implemented killing it also in joinutil function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `joinUntil` interrupts unfinished tasks but your code is not allowing interrupt properly as you are trapping `InterruptedException` here:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Just change above code to re-throw `RuntimeException` or replace `wait.accept(Duration.ofSeconds(1));` by `Thread.sleep(1000L);` so that you don't ignore `InterruptedException`:

```
Callable<String> callableBlocking = () -> {
    while (true) {
        log.accept("fetchFail.callableBlocking.while");
        Thread.sleep(1000L);    
    }
};
```

You can also simplify the code without shutdown/close as try-with-resources and `.ShutdownOnFailure()` deal with this for you:

```
try (var scope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing why exception is needed in java. For 20 years, all i do is getting rid of them. Now it is really needed. Me, coding microhips all the time, even could not see the usage of InterruptedException in Java.

Comment: @TugalsanKarabacak Yes, if you catch `InterruptedException` it is good policy to do any cleanup needed (maybe shutting down other threads or mark isRunning=false), reset the Thread interrupt flag with `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` and exit that thread processing gracefully - and make sure calling app knows exit was not successful.